# Wordpress : You don't have permission to access /test_dir/ on this server

Tags: wordpress

Hello I am unable to access my folder placed on root directory. have the following error 
"You don't have permission to access /test_dir/ on this server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a GUI (desktop) FTP application, right-click (command-click) the folder, choose **File permissions** and set them to `777`.

Screencaptures using [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use shell to locate your self to the parent folder of test_dir and Use the command:

```
sudo chmod 777 test_dir
```

Comment: sorry i did'nt get your solution would u please clarify?